How can a make 2 slide toggle with custom color on same page?
Hwo i can change How can a make 2 slide toggle with custom color on same page?
How can a make 2 slide toggle with custom color on same page?How can a make 2 slide toggle with custom color on same page?How can a make 2 slide toggle with custom color on same page?How can a make 2 slide toggle with custom color on same page?

Please share minimal reproducible code!

Refer this.
You will have to use Styled component to create colored Switches(toggle).
Please clarify if your require something else.

I wannted this in Angular
